# Is there a single HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS debugger?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I know that there is a varity of HTML5 debuggers (such as in Dreamweaver), a vareity of JavaScript (such as JSLint), and CSS debuggers (such as Firebug), but is there a single program that will debug my HTML5, JS, and CSS? And is it free?

Comment: You would be better rephrasing that question as: "Is there an integrated development environment (IDE) that contains a javascript and CSS debugger for my HTML5, JavaScript and CSS projects?"

Answer (score 10):

- Firebug for Firefox http://getfirebug.com/
- Developer tools for IE8 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/07/improved-productivity-through-internet-explorer-8-developer-tools.aspx
- Chrome Developer tools http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/

They all let you debug JS, examine CSS and HTML, and they are all free.

I prefer those over IDE built-in debuggers since they are usually implemented using firefox and you're out of luck if you have a webkit/IE problem. Maybe one day, IDEs will let you debug using any browser, until then, I use the IDE just for editing the code. Yeah, I know, not nearly as integrated, but that's all we have for now.

Answer (score 2):

For stuff like this I just use the built in tools in Chrome, or Firebug in Firefox if you swing that way. This is very handy for debugging JS and CSS, not sure about HTML5 though.

Answer (score 0):

You might like [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) from JetBrains.  It's not free, but the fee is nominal.

Comment: I love WebStorm (PHPStorm actuall), but it doesn't really provide any HTML or CSS debugging. It'll debug using FF, but I haven't got it to understand my source code since it doesn't match 1 to 1 with the deployed location.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Web Developer express could help with all of this functionality and is free.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome you can just right click, Inspect Element and then click

Answer (score 0):

I just released a tool that allows you to visualize your HTML / CSS layout just by moving the mouse.  It doesn't do it all, but its easy and its great for viewing layout problems.

[HTML Box Visualizer - GitHub](https://github.com/ghmcadams/boxvis)