# How to check if HTTP requests are open in browser?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is there an easy way to detect if an `XMLHttpRequest` is active in the browser window? Or how many are active? ie. Is there a way to detect if there are any AJAX calls active in my browser window?

**Extension of question:** Using javascript is there a way I can see if any XMLHttpRequests are open? Such as `"window.XMLisActive()"` or something like that?

Solution: Ended up writing a wrapper for `XMLHttpRequest`: [gist here](https://gist.github.com/1820380)

Comment: What do you mean by active? Can you expand the question a little more, like how are you trying to accomplish this, what have you tried etc.?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is not a way to detect an open connection from JS unless you write a wrapper for `XmlHttpRequest` (or monkey patch it) that keeps track of opened connections.

Here's kidcapital's monkey patch, not sure if it's perfect, but it's a good start

```
  (function() {
    var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    window.openHTTPs = 0;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
      window.openHTTPs++;
      this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
          if(this.readyState == 4) {
            window.openHTTPs--;
          }
        }, false);
      oldOpen.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
    }
  })();
```

**Note**

This does not handle `fetch` or websockets but you could do something similar in those cases.

Comment: ended up writing a gist for it which can be found here https://gist.github.com/1820380

Comment: @kidcapital: I posted something very similar here, but didn't take the time to finish it, so I removed it. Did you look at it for the 30 seconds that it was posted? It looks almost exactly like what I had ;) In any case, be sure to test for network errors, and `abort()` being called

Comment: haha i didn't see it. the network errors will still trigger the responseCode 4 though? will double check on abort()

Comment: after injecting this script into the browser for selenium tests my application stopped working. does this block my application calls.

Comment: Tried injecting this code with a `setInterval` call that logs the variable each second, it worked without any problems. So it should not mess up any application. If it does, a developer who is familiar with js debugging should double-check it... :) We will be testing this approach for test-automation for being able to know if no ajax-request is open at the moment, or for notifiying if all requests have been finished...

Comment: @Martin Note that this is a really old question, and you probably also need to handle `fetch()`

Comment: @JuanMendes, that is correct, however our App uses a Vaadin Version that relies 100% on XHR Requests, so for the use case it is ok...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com) for that.

[image]

Comment: Or any of the other browser development environments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445759/is-there-a-single-html5-javascript-and-css-debugger/4445828#4445828

Answer (score 2):

I tried @juan-mendes's solution and got an error: `ERROR Error Code: undefined Message: Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': The response type cannot be changed for synchronous requests made from a document.`
in my Angular application. The cause is the `async` parameter which is supposed to be true by default, but when the argument is missing, this patch passes `undefined` which translates to false. The code with this small change works for me:

```
(function() {
        var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
        window.openHTTPs = 0;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async = true, user = null, pass = null) {
            window.openHTTPs++;
            this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
                if(this.readyState == 4) window.openHTTPs--;
            }, false);
            oldOpen.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
        }
    })()
```

Answer (score 1):

By using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), you can keep track if there are open requests with the global event handlers: [.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

A global variable set on ajaxStart and reset on ajaxComplete should do the job.

Comment: This assumes you are using jquery .ajax though. What if you have no jQuery ibrary?

Comment: This is what my answer mentioned, if you have a wrapper for `XmlHttpRequest`, it's easy to do (if your wrapper supports it). If you don't have jQuery, you can either start using it, or write your own wrapper.

Comment: The correct pairing is ajaxSend and ajaxComplete (check the docs)