# Run a function if a ajax get/post is fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

As my title indicates, I need to run a function if any ajax get/post is fired.

I tried using

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        console.log('a');
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        console.log('c');
    });
```

but it runs only for the first time.

Later it does not log anything. What am I doing wrong?

I need to do this in chrome extension and on google image search page, so after 100 images it fire a ajax function to get more image data and show on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want it to work even if AJAX requests are not made with jQuery with a technique like [How to check if HTTP requests are open in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267451/how-to-check-if-http-requests-are-open-in-browser/9267519#9267519)

```
(function() {
  var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
  XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
    console.log('Request went out', arguments);
    oldOpen.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Yes, it works when I try to do it locally, but not with chrome extension. Do you have knowledge how to do it via chrome extension?

Comment: @kannu You have to inject the code onto the page, not run in the context of the extension. You can then communicate back using custom events See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/227299

Comment: Can you also guide which thing should I look to communicate between injected script and executeScript? I am adding my main source of code using executeScript. If I able to run function again when ajax request went out then my mail problem will be sort out.

Comment: @kannu You should post a separate question showing what you've tried and what your current problem is. At StackOverflow, we like a question to be about a single problem so they can be most useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   success: function(){ 
      callYourFunctionHere();
   }
});
```

OR

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSend", function(){
   alert('ajax fired');
   callYourFunctionHere();
});
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Does this work with any `XMLHttpRequest`, or only with `$.ajax` requests?

Comment: @Fahad, it says `Now, make an Ajax request using any jQuery method`. I'm just wondering how it would trigger it on a page that doesn't use jQuery, like Google Image Search. It could probably modify the `XmlHttpRequest` object, but I'd imagine that is frowned upon.

Comment: @redbmk are you also trying to do it with google image search?

Comment: @kannu, no, I just read that in your question. I like that you can get events for all jQuery ajax requests, but I'm not convinced yet it'll work with native ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax method itself can accept functions in `beforeSend` and `complete`.

```
.ajax({
  // the rest of your parameters
  complete: function(data) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

If you do not want to specify these on a per-request basis, you can do so with the `.ajaxSetup' function which modifies the defaults.

```
.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function() {
    // custom logic
  },
  complete: function() {
    // custom logic
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to use it with chrome extension and check if any website is sending ajax request.

Comment: Seems to me that the chunk of code you are using to query the Google image API could be provided. Is it not in the the JavaScript world?