# How can I input data to Javascript for client-side processing?

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I am working on a new application. Based on the results of four drop-down selections, I would like to calculate and display a text box announcing the result. The code below allows me to make my selections on the html form and press the "submit" button, but no results are returned.

I'm having a hard time debugging because I don't understand how to get periodic output on screen (document.write doesn't seem to work) to interpret program flow. I'm not even sure if the js is running...do I somehow need to call my js from within the HTML? Do I need to store my js in an external file and call that external file?

Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <SCRIPT type="text\Javascript" EVENT="onclick">
    var valueCS ;
    var valueV ;
    var valueVCS ;
    var valueStorm ;
    var finalValue = valueCS + valueV + valueVCS + valueStorm;
    var startOutage ;
    var outageEnd ;

    document.write="total is "+finalValue;
    if(finalValue==0000) {startOutage="28"; outageEnd="1";} else
      (finalValue==0001) {startOutage="27"; outageEnd="1";} else
      (finalValue==1110) {startOutage="22"; outageEnd="4";} else
      (finalValue==1111) {startOutage="24"; outageEnd="4";} else
      document.write("Invalid entries")
    document.write("Start Outage: "+startOutage<br>"Outage End: "+outageEnd)
    </SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<form id = "outageSelector" method="post contServer=1000&vistaServer=100&vistaCSServer=10&storm=1&submitServerStatus=View+Outage+Groups">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h1>Please choose the status of each system</h1></legend>
        <label>Is the contact server up?</label>
        <select id="contServer" name="contServer">
            <option valueCS=1000>Up</option>
            <option valueCS=0>Down</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Is the Vista server up?</label>
        <select id="vistaServer" name="vistaServer">
            <option valueV=100>Up</option>
            <option valueV=0>Down</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Is VistaCS up?</label>
        <select id="vistaCSServer" name="vistaCSServer">
            <option valueVCS=10>Up</option>
            <option valueVCS=0>Down</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Is the outage due to a storm?</label>
        <select id="storm" name="storm">
            <option valueStorm=1>Yes</option>
            <option valueStorm=0>No</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submitServerStatus" value="View Outage Groups" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What browser are you using to debug with?

Comment: @ltiong_sh - IE8...it's the only one that I've got available to me here... :\

Comment: Dang, a web developer that only has access to IE? Do you work at a prison or something?

Comment: @JuanMendes - lol...almost. I work in a user area. it's like coding with one letters f, s, and t taken away from the keyboard.

Comment: Hmm..interesting.  Is there another page that this FORM is posting to?  Or are you just using the js to pop something onscreen?

Comment: @litong_sh  just trying to get JS to pop up the `document.write("Start Outage: "+startOutage<br>"Outage End: "+outageEnd)` message, populated with appropriate variables based on what servers are up or down...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is with your FORM.  All of your  dropdowns had the same name.  Also your  values were incorrect formatted.

```
<form id="outageSelector" method="post" action="[SOME_DESTINATION]">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h1>Please choose the status of each system</h1></legend>
        <label>Is the contact server up?</label>
        <select id="contServer" name="contServer">
            <option value=1000>Up</option>
            <option value=0>Down</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Is the Vista server up?</label>
        <select id="vistaServer" name="vistaServer">
            <option value=100>Up</option>
            <option value=0>Down</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Is VistaCS up?</label>
        <select id="vistaCSServer" name="vistaCSServer">
            <option value=10>Up</option>
            <option value=0>Down</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Is the outage due to a storm?</label>
        <select id="storm" name="storm">
            <option value=1>Yes</option>
            <option value=0>No</option>
        </select><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submitServerStatus" value="View Outage Groups" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is sent along w/ the POST behind the scenes:

```
contServer=1000&vistaServer=100&vistaCSServer=10&storm=1&submitServerStatus=View+Outage+Groups
```

**EDIT:** here's a revised js function.

```
<script>
  function checkValues(){
    var e;
    e = document.getElementById("contServer");
    var valueCS = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

    e = document.getElementById("vistaServer");
    var valueV = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

    e = document.getElementById("vistaCSServer");
    var valueVCS = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

    e = document.getElementById("storm");
    var valueStorm = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

    var finalValue = valueCS + valueV + valueVCS + valueStorm;
    var startOutage = -1;
    var outageEnd = -1;        

    if(finalValue == 0) {
      startOutage = "28";
      outageEnd = "1";
    } else if (finalValue == 1) {
      startOutage = "27";
      outageEnd = "1";
    } else if (finalValue == 1110) {
      startOutage = "22";
      outageEnd = "4";
    } else if (finalValue == 1111) {
      startOutage = "24";
      outageEnd = "4";
    }

    var msg = "total: " + finalValue;        
    if(startOutage == -1){
      msg += " | Start Outage: " + startOutage + " | Outage End: " + outageEnd;
    }else{
      msg += " | Invalid entries";
    }

    alert(msg);
  }
</script>
```

You'll need to modify your form to use.

```
<form id="outageSelector" method="post" action="" onsubmit="checkValues()"> ...
```

Comment: Aha. I can see the parameters in the address bar, changing as I change the dropdown options. I don't get a result back, however. No errors that I can SEE, but all the dropdown values return to their original states. I do not see my output... `document.write("Start Outage: "+startOutage<br>"Outage End: "+outageEnd)`.  :(

Comment: if you're not really POSTing anywhere..you can leave the 'action' out.

Comment: Excellent, @ltiong_sh. I'm still having a few issues; the return value for `finalValue` keeps coming back as an object whose value displays as `NaN`; I suspect that I need something similar to Java's deepToString() to read it? Are you aware of anything like that? I'm going to post that as a separate question...

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642582/is-there-a-javascript-equivalent-of-javas-deeptostring

Answer (score 1):

To get output on the screen, you should use `console.log` along with Firebug, Chrome dev tools, or IE dev tools. See [Is there a single HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445759/is-there-a-single-html5-javascript-and-css-debugger/4445828#4445828)

One obvious problem in your code is

```
 if(finalValue=1110)
```

Should be (double equals for comparison)

```
if(finalValue==1110)
```

But there's another problem, a number that starts with a zero is an octal. That is

```
010 == 8 // true
```

It seems like you're after a bitmask

```
var mask = 0;
var flagA = 1, flagB = 2, flagC = 4;

// Add flagA and flagB to the mask
mask = mask | flagA; // or mask |= flagA
mask |= flagB;

// Now you can test which flags are on using bit testing

// is flagA set?
console.log(mask & flagA) // truthy value
// is flagC set?
console.log(mask & flagC) // false (0)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @ltiong_sh - findOutageGroups was from an earlier iteration...code updated

Comment: There are plenty of other problems... I didn't mention them all. I figured I'll let the OP figure them out once they figure out how to use the dev tools.

Comment: Thanks for the == tip & the octal reminder. Completely spaced on that. I don't think that I should have problems with that; I'm generating a binary number to represent the four on/off positions of the yes/no switches...1000 or 0 for the first slot, 100 or 0 for the second, then adding them together. However, that begs the question: Will 1000+100+10 = 1110 or 13? that could be my problem....

Comment: @JuanMendes - Nor I. :)  I meant to type 14 (1110 binary = 14 decimal)

Comment: I see it more like assuming the numbers were binary. 1000 (8) + 100 + (4) + 10 (2) equals 14 though

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `document.write` at all, but [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/About_the_Document_Object_Model) manipulation. Read [these](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/dombasics) [introductions](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/jsp/article.php/3594621/Javascript-Basics-Part-6.htm).

Also, you will need to learn about [event-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). You'll need [domevents](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) ([intro](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)), but also asynchronous communication to the server is event-based. `<SCRIPT type="text\Javascript" EVENT="onclick">` is not the way it works :-)

Answer (score 0):

Juan already gave you console.log, which is very useful, and probably the best.  Firebug, Chrome Dev and IE dev will also allow you to add break points and watch local and global variables.

Older styles of debugging from the dark ages would include using `alert("some string here");` to get a popup or add a debug element to your page and then populating it with

```
document.getElementById("debugElement").innerHTML("some string here");
```