# Is there a JavaScript equivalent of Java's deepToString()?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on debugging some javascript, and keep running into a javascript `[object]` (e.g., whenI display an alert with the value, it dsplays as `[object]` or `NaN`). I'm trying to read the contents of this object. I know in Java, this would be a perfect job for `deepToString();` Is there any javascript equivalent to that method?

Here's the code generating the aforementioned object...

```
e = document.getElementById("contServer");  // contServer is an integer variable  
var valueCS = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value); 
    //Value CS is a four-byte variable calculated from e
```

Any ideas for a javascript way to 'decode' this object variable so I can see what's *actually* inside?

Thanks

Comment: If you log the object to console, `console.log`, you can inspect the object.

Comment: the code you have above should output an integer or string in javascript, you are saying it outputs an object?

Comment: Are you using any Javascript library? For example,in extjs, you can do Ext.util.JSON.decode(document.getElementById("contServer"));

Comment: @Huangism - I'm not sure. Based on the rest of the code, `contServer` is set to either `0` or `1000`, so I am expecting integer output. However, when I display the `valueCS` using `alert()`, it shows up as `NaN`. Definitely not an integer. :) I was guessing that `valueCS` was perhaps cast as an array object rather than an integer, and was hoping to confirm that somehow...does that make sense, though?

Comment: alert or console e and see what it returns, then find out what e.options[e.selectedIndex].value returns and so on. you will pin down where the problem is. can you provide html of contServer

Comment: @Huangism Original HTML code is posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638942/how-can-i-input-data-to-javascript-for-client-side-processing 
e returns `[object]`; this makes sense to me...as I understand it, valueCS is similar to a Java ArrayList, no?

Comment: oh lol no wonder you are getting NaN i will write an answer to this

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok so after looking at your original html code

```
    <select id="contServer" name="contServer">
        <option valueCS=1000>Up</option>
        <option valueCS=0>Down</option>
    </select>
```

this is invalid html, below is how an option should look like

```
<option selected="selected" value="1000">Up</option>
```

if you do the same code this will return 1000, which is the value attribute

if you have something like the below

```
<option selected="selected" value="0">1000</option>
```

your code will return 0, because value is set to 0. This should get you on your way to correct our code

Comment: This should have been a comment

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some confusion when working with `select` elements.

Make sure your have proper markup:

```
​<select id="contServer">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="10">Ten</option>
  <option value="100" selected>Hundred</option>
  <option value="1000">Thousand</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

We store our value in the `value` attribute of the `option` elements. If that attribute isn't present, the `value` will be the text that sits the opening `option` tag and the closing `option` tag.

Next, "integer" values like those above are not actually integers - they're strings. And as such they must be parsed before they can be used for any math. In the short walk-through below I explain the process of grabbing the selected value, and parsing it to an integer. Please read it studiously and I think it will clear up a lot of confusion:

```
// We now have a reference to the select object (with all of its object members)
var cServer = document.getElementById("contServer");

// Now we have a reference to all of the options within the select object
var options = cServer.options;

// Now a reference to the selected option
var selected = options[ cServer.selectedIndex ];

// And now the value of the selected option
var selValue = selected.value;

// Let's get the type of this value
var selType = typeof selValue;

// Convert this String to an Integer
var iSelType = parseInt( selType, 10 );

// We can also get the value from the select object itself
var cServerVal = cServer.value;

// But we would still need to parse it to an integer
var iCServerVal = parseInt( cServerVal, 10 );
```

I believe your problem with `NaN` is coming from an attempt to parse a non-numerical value. For instance, we we were to try and parse a word to an integer:

```
parseInt( "Hundred" );
```

The result will be `NaN`. This is likely what happened with you. Make sure you store your numbers either between the `option` tags, or within the `value` attribute on each one of the `option` tags.

Comment: I voted down because the script he put on should output object

Comment: @Huangism The OP said that was the problem. He's trying to convert the object to a string that can be read.

Comment: true but if you look at his code, he is simply confused with why it is not returning the desired result

Comment: @Huangism I really don't think it's worth a downvote based on the confusion in the OP's question. However, I've approached the question again after having seen the OP's *other* question, and have modified my answer.

Comment: I have changed the down to an up

Answer (score 2):

Use the [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function to output your object as a JSON string

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in "object dumper" in JavaScript.  A quick and easy way, as others have said, is `JSON.stringify()`.   In case you want some variety & to kick it old school... you can use a recursive function that does `for (var key in obj) {}`.

I tote something like this with me in my JS toolbox...

```
var MAX_DUMP_DEPTH = 10;
function dumpObj(obj, name, indent, depth) {
    if (depth > MAX_DUMP_DEPTH) {
        return indent + name + ":  Over Max Depth\n";
    }
    if (typeof obj == "object") {
        var child = null;
        var output = indent + name + "\n";
        indent += "\t";

        for (var item in obj) {
            try {
                child = obj[item];
            } catch (e) {
                child = "wtf was that?";
            }

            if (typeof child == "object") {
                output += dumpObj(child, item, indent, depth + 1);
            } else {
                output += indent + item + ": " + child + "\n";
            }
        }
        return output;
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
```