# appendChild is "eating" the children

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I have a structure which is a big div container:

```
var bigcontainer = document.createElement('div');
```

which contains three items: A header, a set of buttons and the main information:

```
var divheader = document.createElement('div');
var divbuttons = document.createElement('div');
var divinfo = document.createElement('div');
```

Those three items are separated, none of them are inside each other. They are three separate entities inside the big div container.

Can they be considered children of `bigcontainer` ?

I do this:

```
bigcontainer.appendChild(divheader);
bigcontainer.appendChild(divbuttons);
bigcontainer.appendChild(divinfo);
```

and buttons and header vanish. The only one remaining visible is the `divinfo`. Does that mean that header and buttons wouldn't count as children of `bigcontainer`?

Thank you for any help. I am having a difficult time understanding the DOM tree, but I will get there...

Comment: There is something else going on in there.

Comment: Show an example. It looks like it should work. Also use a debugger to see the rendered HTML structure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445759/is-there-a-single-html5-javascript-and-css-debugger/4445828#4445828

Comment: Nothing you describe can be observed when your code is run. http://jsfiddle.net/9LU7m/ To make it a little clearer, here's the  same thing but with IDs on the elements. http://jsfiddle.net/9LU7m/1/

Comment: They can't vanish; they were never in the DOM to begin with. If anything, using appendChild *adds* them to the DOM.

Comment: I update with the whole jsfiddle code in one second...

Comment: @telex-wap I'm still around if you have that jsfiddle.

Comment: @Asad Thanks, but the fiddle is not working in the same way as in my machine, it's acting different (not proper either) so I will have a second look at it before trying again.

Comment: @PeeHaa I can't believe I never heard *omnomnomnom* before , after reading http://www.omnomnomnom.com/random/index.php and http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=omnomnomnomnom, I still don't know what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to insert them into two different places? If so, `appendChild` will move a node from where it was previously.